# startActivityForResult() for selecting image, why do I not get RESULT_OK?

Tags: android

In my simple Activity I launch the selection of an image.

On the result of the selection i want to show the image.

But debugging I see that `resultCode == RESULT_OK` is not `true`.

What am i doing wrong here???

```
public class PictureActivity extends Activity {
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setData(data.getData());
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What result code are you getting?

Comment: @Mus thank you Mus, i am getting 0

Comment: use `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);` instead of flag

Comment: See my code. It will let you select an image from gallery and show it in a imageview as a Preview because you have written above "On the result of the selection i want to show the image."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

From the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

"This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from the activity being launched."

Comment: onActivityResult , you want's to show the image. This answer does not point to that. You will still not get the image to show even if you remove this line of code and also you are calling intent again in activity result. I fail to understand why. I mean you click a button, you select an image, then it goes to activity result and again the gallery opens and it will go on and on

Comment: The title of this question is 'why do I not get RESULT_OK?' and my answer explains exactly that. The question does not ask about specific issues (that there may or may not be) with the code that displays the image.

Answer (score 0):

Use my Code :-

```
  Uri selectedImageUri; // Global Variable
  String  selectedPath; // Global Variable
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView preview = findViewById(R.id.preview);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select file to upload "), 10);
    } 


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {



        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         if(data.getData() != null){
           selectedImageUri = data.getData();
         }else{
          Log.d("selectedPath1 : ","Came here its null !");
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed to get Image!", 500).show();
         }

            if (requestCode == 10)

            {

               selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
               preview.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
               Log.d("selectedPath1 : " ,selectedPath);

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: You have not defined `getPath(Uri)`.